# A kind of cancellation ; exchange problem for groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, normal-subgroups

For which $(m,n,k,l) \in (\mathbb N\cup \{0\})^4$ , with $m\le n ; k\le l$ , does there exist a group $G$ with a finite subnormal series with torsion-free Abelian quotients such that $G \times \mathbb Z^n \cong G \times \mathbb Z^l$ but $G \times \mathbb Z^m \ncong G \times \mathbb Z^k$ ?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218113/a-is-isomorphic-to-a-oplus-mathbbz2-but-not-to-a-oplus-mathbbz  shows $(0,0,1,2)$ is such a pair .

Comment: Crossposted to MathOF: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277080/a-kind-of-cancellation-exchange-problem-for-groups